# Did the Beta badges wander off?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

In other Beta sites that I've been involved with, the Beta badges are normally given at the end of the private Beta period.

Since things are beginning to [change](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5102/5) in the Area 51 process, and the extension of the duration of the private Beta period may have been indicative of this, is the Beta badge going to be awarded on a different schedule now?

(the temptation is to ask if the criteria to earn the badge have changed, but that appears to [still be under wraps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) for the 2.0 sites the last time I looked into it)

Comment: [We have 'em now](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: beta badges have have arrived.**

---

On [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), the latest public beta, the beta badges were awarded approximately 12 days after the site went into public beta. Another source tells me the badges will arrive on Tuesday.